# Issue Width of header and content is different for same column for data table why this happen?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I work on asp.net MVC I face issue  cell header width different from width of cell content details for same column for data table .

so how to make cell header width and cell details content to be same

I make red marks to columns not have same width header and details as `request date` and `Dept.Manager` columns and others etc.

I using data table as below  my code details as below

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px; margin-top: 10px; border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 50px; width: 100%; padding-left: 2em; padding-right: 2em;padding-bottom: 2em;">

    <h2 style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 40px;">My Requests</h2>

    <table id="dtbl" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">

                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Request No

                </th>

                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Request Date

                </th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Reason

                </th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Line Manager

                </th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Dept.Manager

                </th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    Employee Remarks

                </th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">View Resignation Form</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;">Print(Resignation)</th>

                <th style="border: 1px solid black; display: none">Exit Interview</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.MyRequests)
            {
                <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">

                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequestNo)
                    </td>

                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                       
                        @Convert.ToDateTime(item.ResignationSubmissionDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Reason)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">

                        @if (item.LineManagerStatus == "Waiting for Line Manager Approval")
                        {
                            <span>Pending</span>
                        }
                        else if (item.LineManagerStatus == "Rejected by Line Manager")
                        {
                            <span>Rejected</span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LineManagerStatus)
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @if (item.DirectManagerStatus == "Waiting for Department Head Approval")
                        {
                            <span>Pending</span>
                        }
                        else if (item.DirectManagerStatus == "Rejected by Head Department")
                        {
                            <span>Rejected</span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DirectManagerStatus)
                        }

                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        @if (item.RevokeRequest == "1")
                        {
                            <span>Cancelled</span>
                        }

                        else
                        {

                        }

                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                        
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">

                       

                    </td>

                    <td style="border: 1px solid black; display: none">
                        <a class="exitinterview">Exit Interview</a>

                    </td>

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

and on jQuery i do as below

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#dtbl').DataTable({
      "scrollX": true,
      "pageLength": 10,
      "dom": 't', // Only show the table without search and other elements
      "language": {
          "search": "", // Empty string to remove the search text
          "searchPlaceholder": "" // Empty string to remove the search input
      },
      initComplete: function () {
          $('.buttons-excel, .buttons-pdf, .buttons-print, .buttons-csv, .buttons-copy').remove();
      }
  });
});
```

my issue display on image below

[image: cell header and details content not same]

**updated post**

can you show  me please how to use css instead of bootstrap to solve issue .

Comment: All those inline styles really make life difficult. Also, it looks like you're using the Bootstrap library, which can do much of that for you with classes. Please use CSS and your library instead.

Comment: My suggestion was that you clean up your code so we can more easily resolve the problem. This is basic best practice. Are you in fact using Bootstrap? If so, please tag it by version.

Comment: i'm not use bootstrap